# Disabling consoleblank on running systems without logging into the console

Tags: rhel, console

I have recently added `consoleblank=0` to my kernel boot line in order to disable the console screensaver on hosts that are either VMs are are connected to some sort of KVM.

This obviously only takes effect on reboot.  I would like to make this change for all my running systems without rebooting.

There are [a few existing answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138918/how-do-i-disable-the-blank-console-screensaver-on-ubuntu-server) that deal with this in terms of the `setterm` command, but they all say that [it must be run on the VT itself](https://superuser.com/questions/152347/change-linux-console-screen-blanking-behavior/154388#154388).  I'd like to apply this change to a few hundred machines and I want to avoid having to log into each one's console by hand and run this command.

How can I disable `consoleblank` across my server estate without either (a) rebooting or (b) logging into each console by hand?

I'm running a mixture of RHEL 6 and RHEL 7.

Comment: I would have thought running `TERM=linux setterm -blank 0 < /dev/tty1 > /dev/tty1` as `root` would work, but apparently not...

Comment: @StephenKitt Doesn't it? `TERM=linux setterm --blank force </dev/tty1` works for me. I don't have the patience to test the timeout feature.

Answer (score 1):

`man console_codes` lists the escape sequences recognised by the console. You can set a timeout of 0 with

```
sudo sh -c 'echo -e "\033[9;0]" >/dev/console'
```